# Got linking error after 'Enable Modules' in iOS 7

Tags: module, ios7, afnetworking

The error happened when I was transferring my app from iOS6 to iOS7 when applying one of the new objective-c features--- **Modules**.

Here is the situation:

1. I turned **Enable Modules(C and Objective-C)** to **YES** in the project settings.
2. Since Auto Linking is enabled for system frameworks, I deleted the reference of all the system frameworks under **Build Phases ---> Link Binary With Libraries**
   (Note that I also delete the reference under the Project Navigator--->Frameworks directory).
3. Then I built my app and got the linking errors.
4. Finally after several try, I figured out that I still need to import
   **MobileCoreServices.framework** and **SystemConfiguration.framework**(both of them are system frameworks, I think)because I am using `AFNetworking` library in my project.
   Anyone has idea why I have to refer them though others don't need to be(such as UIKit or Foundation, both of them are also used in AFNetworking library...)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you update your `import`s accordingly? (i.e.: `#import` to `@import`.)

Comment: @middaparka No, I didn't. Cause apple doc says: `#import` and `#include` automatically mapped to `@import`.